# Cocoa Programming - MouseEntered while button is pressed?

Tags: cocoa, events, mouseenter

I am trying to find a way to get a MouseEntered event to fire or at least detect when the mouse button is pressed while entering the region.

If the mouse enters the tracking region with the left button pressed, is there any way to detect this event?

Is there a different event I could perhaps use to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, assuming that you have your tracking area set up to receive mouse entered and exited events:

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    if ([[NSApp currentEvent] type] == NSLeftMouseDown) {
       NSLog(@"mouse is pressed");
    }
}
```